# Nativescript PUSH technology

Tags: http, https, push, nativescript

Hi I was wondering if nativescript offers any module that sends http/https request on the background once the wifi of the device is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miguel - there is a plugin for background http requests. You can use the `connectivity` module from NativeScript to determine what type of connection a device has.

- https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/connectivity
- https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http